# Type Casting in Java

Tags: java

Could anyone explain why short(100000) is -31072 as said in p.48 of [java-notes](http://1drv.ms/12estXQ).The article says that "the value -31072 is obtained by taking the the 4 byte int 100000 and throwing away two of these bytes to obtain a short".

The code in the article related to the question is:

```
int A;
short B;
A = 17;
B = (short)A;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Java, `int`s are stored using a 32-bit [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation and `short`s with a 16-bit 2's complement representation.

This means that an `int` with the value 17 will contain the bitpattern `00000000 00000000 000000000 00010001` and with the value 100000 it will contain the bitpattern `00000000 00000001 10000110 10100000`.

When converting these numbers to `short`, you need to stuff them in 16 bits. This is done by keeping the lower (right-most) 16 bits and throwing the rest away, as that preserves any value that can be represented in a `short`.
The pattern for 17 becomes `00000000 00010001`, which still is the number 17.
The pattern for 100000 becomes `10000110 10100000`. Here we have lost one bit that was actually needed for the representation of the number, so the value represented by the remaining bits is different. According to 16-bit 2'complement representation,the bitpattern `10000110 10100000` represents the number -31072.

Comment: maybe I am missing something in your demonstration, but I would have said that the binary representation of 17 is `10001` rather than `1001`

Comment: @Seki: Good catch. I have corrected it.